# find the longest even occurence in a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list like:

```
['a', 'aaa', 'aa', 'aaaa']
```

I want to find out all the evenelements in the list, if there's more than 1, then take the longest.

expected results should be like this

```
output: ['aaaa', 4]
```

'aa' and 'aaaa' are of even lenght, but 'aaaa' is longer and its position is 4 in the list.

I'm sure I have to use `enumerate` but I have no idea how to do this using python since I'm a mysql user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the maximum length of the even lengths and the index associated with that. You can do that by [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)ing a list of the lengths of the elements in the list and taking the `max` based on the length. This will give you the index of the longest value which you can then use to refer back into the list. Note since python indexes start at 0, you need to add 1 to get a "position" of 4:

```py
l = ['a', 'aaaaa', 'zz', 'aaaa']
# find the index of the maximum length where the length is even
m = max((ln, idx) for idx, ln in enumerate([len(s) for s in l]) if ln % 2 == 0)
# get the value from that index and its index
output = [l[m[1]], m[1]+1]
print(output)
```

Output:

```py
['aaaa', 4]
```

This can be made into a one-liner by [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ing the lengths with the original values, although this is less efficient than the prior code:

```py
output = max([ln, val, idx+1] for idx, (ln, val) in enumerate(zip([len(s) for s in l], l)) if ln % 2 == 0)[1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
l = ['a', 'aaa', 'zz', 'aaaa']
filtered = {
  len(s): [s, idx]
  for idx, s in enumerate(l, start=1)
  if not len(s) % 2
}

filtered
{2: ['zz', 3], 4: ['aaaa', 4]}

filtered[max(filtered)]
['aaaa', 4]
```

Explanation:

You first build a dict where the keys are the string length, the values a list [string, position in initial list], but only for the even length strings.
Then, using max you get the biggest key (longest string length), which value can be retrieved from the filtered dict via the key found by max.

Answer (score 1):

Just some more ways:

```
output = max([len(s), s, i]
             for i, s in enumerate(a, 1)
             if not len(s) % 2
            )[1:]
```

```
s = max((s for s in a if not len(s) % 2), key=len)
output = [s, a.index(s) + 1]
```

```
output = max(([s, i]
              for i, s in enumerate(a, 1)
              if not len(s) % 2),
             key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
```

Comment: the second one is interesting, but I just hate using list.index in general, still upvote for using key=len

Comment: @AnthonyPerot Why?

Comment: because it's super heavy on long lists compared to using dict access by key

Comment: @AnthonyPerot It might be less heavy than enumerating a lof of indices that you end up throwing away (depends on how heavy the element comparisons are).